# SELECT COUNT for column in database?

Tags: php, sql

How to Count number of rows in a table that matches to the related condition and echo that count out.

Code goes as follows::

```
<?php 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM input ORDER BY date DESC";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
     $myid = $row["id"] ;
 $sql3 = "SELECT COUNT question_id FROM output WHERE question_id = $myid";
    $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
?>

<div id="q">

        <small><p><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></p></small>
        <p id="tag3"><small><?php echo $result3['']; ?></small></p>
</div>
```

Any Suggestions will be appreciated..

Comment: check out for quotes and braces

Comment: your question_id is int or varchar ?

Comment: @jothi it is int..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quotes missing**

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * question_id FROM output WHERE question_id = '".$myid."'";
```

Secondly i dont see closing braces for while

```
<?php 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM input ORDER BY date DESC";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
     $myid = $row["id"] ;
$sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as rowCount FROM output WHERE question_id = '".$myid."'";
    $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
$rowCount= $result3->fetch_assoc();
?>

<div id="q">

        <small><p><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></p></small>
        <p id="tag3"><small><?php echo $rowCount['rowCount']; ?></small></p>
</div>
<?php }//while

} //if 

?>
```

Comment: yaa.. they are at the bottom, i forgot to type them and apart from the quotations, is the rest fine.. i mean i still doubt about `$result3[' ']`

Comment: it said some error like 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\the_database\answer.php:867 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\the_database\answer.php on line 867` and the 867 line is `$rowCount= $result3->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: question_id is int it should be treated as integer not as  a string .try to remove single quotes

Comment: And hey i have another thing bugging me like... i have a add comment page. and when i press submit it sends the input to db giving me an alert box saying "your coment has been posted" but it wont show in page until i refresh that page... can you help me with this...

Comment: dont edit the current question .post the new question .people will help you and i too @user6779766

Comment: no i have no intention of editing it. unfortunately my questioning limit for today has reached....

Answer (score 1):

You need to use COUNT(question_id) function as below

```
    $sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(question_id ) as  TotalQuestions FROM output WHERE question_id = $myid";
 $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
```

Then to fetch result from above query use [**fetch_fieled()**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)

```
while ($info = $result3->fetch_field()) {
$TotalCount = $info->TotalQuestions ;
}
```

And then display the value

```
<small><?php echo $TotalCount ; ?></small
```

Comment: the rest is OK?

Comment: `$result3['']` is suspect.. let me check

Comment: it said some error like `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$TotalQuestions in C:\xampp\htdocs\the_database\answer.php on line 868`   where the line 868 is `$TotalCount = $info->TotalQuestions ;`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(1) as row_count FROM output WHERE question_id = ".$myid."";
 $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
 $row_count = $result3->fetch_assoc();

 echo $row_count['row_count'];
```